# What's happening with cin? it goes infinite loop

Tags: c++

I recently coding some basic things for learning: Queue using dynamic memory allocation. I would be painful for some of you to read such a novice-level code, but testing this, I found something funny.

I made my program to ask initial capacity of the queue to the user. In order to test what happens, I typed A instead of an integer value.

```
Welcome! this program provides queue with dynamic memory allocation.
what size of the queue would you want for the starting? minimum would be 100. (type integer)
A
```

(push enter then...)

```
To enqueue, type E and # of elements want to type (e.g.E5)
To dequeue, type D (e.g.D5)
To quit, type Q

queue capacity is now 100
```

above is infinitely printed

**whats actually happening?**

main function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "./Queue2.h"
int main(){
  int initial_size;
  cout << "Welcome! this program provides queue with dynamic memory allocation." << endl;
  cout << "what size of the queue would you want for the starting? minimum would be 100. (type integer)" << endl;
  cin >> initial_size;
  initial_size=(initial_size>=100)? initial_size:100;
  Queue Q = Queue(initial_size); //constructor initialized the queue of 100 rooms with head=0 and tail=0

  char x='\0'; // user input initializing
  do{ // until we get the instructed input, ask repeatedly.
    cout << "To enqueue, type E and # of elements want to type (e.g.E5)" << endl;
    cout << "To dequeue, type D (e.g.D5)" << endl;
    cout << "To quit, type Q" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "queue capacity is now " << Q.getcap() << endl;
    cin >> x;   
    if(x=='Q'){
      cout << "Bye Bye" << endl;
      break;
    }
    else if(x=='E'){
      int numofq, a;
      cin >> numofq;
      for (int i=1; i<=numofq; i++){
        cin >> a;
        Q.enqueue(a);   
      }
    }
    else if(x=='D'){
      int numofdeq;
      cin >> numofdeq;
      for (int i=1; i<=numofdeq; i++){
        cout << Q.dequeue() << endl;
      }
    }
}while(1);

return 0;
}
```

Header:

```
//1.class declaration with different member variables
class Queue{
private:
  int* dataptr;
  int head;
  int tail;
  int capacity;
public:
  Queue(int cap); // constructor
  Queue(int a[], int n);
  ~Queue(); // destructor
  int gethead(); // get head value
  int gettail(); // get tail val
  int getcap(); // get capacity 
  void enqueue(int x);
  //puts some # into queue
  int dequeue(void);
  //returns the element at the head of the queue
  bool isEmpty(void);
  //returns TRUE if queue is empty. 
};
int Queue::gethead(){
  return head;
}
int Queue::gettail(){
  return tail;
}
int Queue::getcap(){
  return capacity;
}
void Queue::enqueue(int x){
  if(tail>=capacity){ //in case tail==capacity, queue is already full
     capacity *=2;
     int* newptr = new int[capacity];
     for(int i=0; i<tail; i++){
       newptr[i]=dataptr[i];
     }
     delete []dataptr;
     dataptr=newptr;
  }
  dataptr[tail++]=x;
  return;
}
int Queue::dequeue(void){
  int y;
  if(head<tail){
    y=dataptr[head++];
  }
  else{
    cout << "error!: nothing to dequeue(queue is empty)"<< endl;
    y=-1;
  }
  return y;
}
bool Queue::isEmpty(void){
  return (head==tail);
}
Queue::Queue(int cap){
  head=0;
  tail=0;
  capacity=(cap>0)? cap:100;
  dataptr=new int[capacity];
}
//3.function overloading: another constructor
Queue::Queue(int a[], int n){
  head=0;
  tail=0;
  capacity=(2*n>=100)? 2*n:100;
  int* ptr= new int[capacity];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    dataptr[i]=a[i];
    tail++;
  }
}
Queue::~Queue(){
  delete []dataptr;
}
```

Comment: You forget that when a user enters some input, for example a number, the user presses the enter key to end the input. That enter key is put into the input buffer of the stream as a newline. So when reading your character it will read the newline and not the next character, and trouble will ensue. You need to [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the rest of the input before the loop iterates.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The code is still broken. Imagine input stream ends...

Comment: Looks like your do while(1) will forever be '1'.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read a character from the stream into an integer . `cin >> initial_size;` gets wrong input `-failbit` is set and cin is not cleared. To clear it you can call `clear()`method. I think the code snipped can be used with `limits` library to overcome.

```
while(!(cin >> initial_size))
{ 
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
    cout << "Invalid input. Try again: " << endl; 
}
```